# Custom postback inside aspx and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to perform a postback in order to process a gateway payment by redirect, so i've got an example in order to do inside an html with server side code (runat=server in the inputs):

```
   <form action="https://xxxxxxxx" method="post">     
        <input runat="server" type="text" id="param1" name="param1" value="asd" />          
        <input runat="server" size="100" type="text" id="parm2" name="parm2" value="asd" />                
        <input runat="server" type="text" size="50" id="param3" name="param3" value="asd" />
        <input runat="server" type="submit" value="Post!" />
    </form>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                              
            // New instance of library and his magic
            LibraryXXX r = new LibraryXXX();        
            r.Parameter.Add("xxxx", xxxx);    
            // more logic goes here    
        }
```

Clinking the submit button sends the postback and the page loads an html.  I want traslate that sample to an aspx webform. The problem is i can't have more than one form label inside an aspx. So, how can i do the same postback inside an aspx?

Comment: Why will you want to duplicate the form element? What is wrong with using the existing one in your ASPX?

Comment: Well, unless there's something in your question that's not stated, you can do server side POST and obtain result prior to rendering anything. I suspect because its a gateway payment, there is a _requirement_ that _nothing_ should be handled on _your side_ - meaning you **can't** postback to your own server prior to sending that (payment) data to gateway? It could be a simple as [Button.PostBackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx). Hth...

Comment: If i add more controls inside the form and capture the request (with fiddler  ) i observe there is more information about the view state and the payment gateway doesn't like that... When set a custom post in the form action =xxx or in the button PostbackUrl=xxx

Comment: Sorry people i've been something wrong about configuration. Thank you! That you told me was usefull.